# Is List<Item> faster than List?

Tags: java, performance, list, arraylist

I am developing a `Java` application with many `List`-s and procedures and I need it to execute very fast. I would like to know when I specify the type elements of a list, if the loops are faster.

An example:

Code 1:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
Item item;
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
int t = list.size();
for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
    item = (Item)list.get(i);
    //...
}
```

Code 2:

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
Item item;
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
int t = list.size();
for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
    item = list.get(i);
    //...
}
```

Is `code 2` faster than `code 1`?

Comment: Why don't **you** measure it?. Also, it should be - List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>(); OR List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

Comment: How are you timing it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think that's the question - Is it faster?

Comment: @cricket_007 Maybe. If you tested example one, then example two the second could be JIT-ed? The question would be more interesting if we knew what OP was doing with the `item`(s).

Comment: @Juan Camacho, Have you measured the performance? Do did you notice the performance difference?

Comment: List<T> should always be faster since it will avoid boxing and at least it is safer since it will produce Compile Time errors and not run time,

Comment: What you are doing is often called *premature optimization*.  Please read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/4160/java-performance-tuning/26153/an-evidence-based-approach-to-java-performance-tuning#t=201612200524324156195.  It explains a better way of optimizing code that will avoid you wasting lots of effort on things with minimal pay-off.

Answer (score 4):

They have the same run-time performance, because Java Generics are implemented using type erasure.  The following description come from the Oracle/Sun tutorial on Java Generics

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

> **Type Erasure**
>
> ...
>
> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized
>   types; consequently, generics **incur no runtime overhead**.

Comment: It's more about that at runtime there are no generic types, there is only `List<Object>`, so generics should not play a big role in the runtime performance.

Answer (score 4):

They will have the exact same performance, because they compile to the exact same code. That's how [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) works: it removes all your `List<Foo>` with `List`, and replaces `Foo foo = list.get(i)` (and similar calls) with `Foo foo = (Foo) list.get(i)`. That's why, for instance, you can't ask if something is `instanceof List<Foo>` — the `<Foo>` information is missing at runtime, since it was erased at compile-time.

You can verify this for yourself. If you take a simple class, like:

```
public class Test {
  public void raw() {
    String s;
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0, t = list.size(); i < t; i++) {
      s = (String) list.get(i);
    }
  }

  public void generic() {
    String s;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0, t = list.size(); i < t; i++) {
      s = list.get(i);
    }
  }
}
```

You can compile it, then decompile it using `javap -c Test` and take a look at both methods. They'll be the same.

```
Code:
   0: new           #2                  // class java/util/ArrayList
   3: dup
   4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
   7: astore_2
   8: iconst_0
   9: istore_3
  10: aload_2
  11: invokeinterface #4,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.size:()I
  16: istore        4
  18: iload_3
  19: iload         4
  21: if_icmpge     41
  24: aload_2
  25: iload_3
  26: invokeinterface #5,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
  31: checkcast     #6                  // class java/lang/String
  34: astore_1
  35: iinc          3, 1
  38: goto          18
  41: return
```

Note in particular the checkcast op at byte 31, with its comment. That's the `(String)` cast.

Answer (score 2):

I expect these two codes to perform almost identically.  The reason is that both versions of your code will actually use the following `List`:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the first case, `Object` is the default type of collection, and in the second case, `List<Item>` will become `List<Object>` after type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

Put these both codes in this program, you will see the result yourself:

```
 class Longest
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
            long start,end;

            start=System.currentTimeMillis();

            //Paste your above code here

            end=System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Take taken by above code to execute:"+(end-start));
     }
   }
```